# Pegar atributo com JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

estou tentando fazer um carrinho de produtos, e até ai tudo bem, já ta funcionando, coisa linda, porém, como sempre, tem os problemas, eu sou meio novo no JS, então to apanhando muito, eu estou tentando pegar o atributo dentro da `data-price` (`data-price="25.99"`) porém eu não estou conseguindo fazer isso para poder adicionar junto ao carrinho, e o mesmo iria pra pegar o nome do produto, cor, quantidade, etc.

HTML

```
<button class="add-to-cart" data-price="25.99">
    <em>Adicionar ao Carrinho</em>
    <svg x="0px" y="0px" width="32px" height="32px" viewBox="0 0 32 32">
        <path stroke-dasharray="19.79 19.79" stroke-dashoffset="19.79" fill="none" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="square" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M9,17l3.9,3.9c0.1,0.1,0.2,0.1,0.3,0L23,11"/>
    </svg>
</button>
```

JS

```
addToCartBtn.on('click', function() {   updateCart(); });
function updateCart() {var cartWrapper = $('.cd-cart-container'),
    cartWrapperPrice = cartWrapper.find('.add-to-cart'),
    cartPrice = cartWrapperPrice.attr('data-price'),
    cartBody = cartWrapper.find('.body'),
    cartList = cartBody.find('.cd-cart-items');
    productAdded = $('<li><span class="cd-qty">1x</span>Produto<div class="cd-price">'+cartPrice+'</div><a href="#" class="cd-item-remove cd-img-replace">Remove</a></li>');
    cartList.prepend(productAdded);};
```

Esse de cima me retorna "undefined".

Esse de baixo, me retorna o preço, mas quando eu testo em outro com valor diferente, ele me retorna somente um valor, como se fosse o um valor para todos produtos.

```
var cartWrapper = $('.cd-cart-container'),
    cartWrapperPrice = $('.add-to-cart'),
    cartPrice = cartWrapperPrice.attr('data-price'),
    cartBody = cartWrapper.find('.body'),
    cartList = cartBody.find('.cd-cart-items');
    productAdded = $('<li><span class="cd-qty">1x</span>Produto<div class="cd-price">'+cartPrice+'</div><a href="#" class="cd-item-remove cd-img-replace">Remove</a></li>');
    cartList.prepend(productAdded);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No primeiro caso, você pode fazer da seguinte forma, enviando o elemento como parâmetro para a função:

```
addToCartBtn.on('click', function() {   updateCart($(this)); });
```

E na função, você pode usar a sintaxe `i.data("price")` para pegar o valor do atributo:

```
function updateCart(i) {
   var cartWrapper = $('.cd-cart-container'),
   cartPrice = i.data("price"),
   cartBody = cartWrapper.find('.body'),
   cartList = cartBody.find('.cd-cart-items');
   productAdded = $('<li><span class="cd-qty">1x</span>Produto<div class="cd-price">'+cartPrice+'</div><a href="#" class="cd-item-remove cd-img-replace">Remove</a></li>');
   cartList.prepend(productAdded);
};
```

No segundo caso, seria quase a mesma coisa:

```
var cartWrapper = $('.cd-cart-container'),
    cartWrapperPrice = $('.add-to-cart'),
    cartPrice = cartWrapperPrice.data('price'),
    cartBody = cartWrapper.find('.body'),
    cartList = cartBody.find('.cd-cart-items');
    productAdded = $('<li><span class="cd-qty">1x</span>Produto<div class="cd-price">'+cartPrice+'</div><a href="#" class="cd-item-remove cd-img-replace">Remove</a></li>');
    cartList.prepend(productAdded);
```

**Veja:**

```js
addToCartBtn= $(".add-to-cart");

addToCartBtn.on('click', function() {   updateCart($(this)); });

var cartWrapper = $('.cd-cart-container'),
    cartWrapperPrice = $('.add-to-cart'),
    cartPrice = cartWrapperPrice.data('price'),
    cartBody = cartWrapper.find('.body'),
    cartList = cartBody.find('.cd-cart-items');
    productAdded = $('<li><span class="cd-qty">1x</span>Produto<div class="cd-price">'+cartPrice+'</div><a href="#" class="cd-item-remove cd-img-replace">Remove</a></li>');
    cartList.prepend(productAdded);
   console.log("Valor fora da função: "+cartPrice);

function updateCart(i) {
   var cartWrapper = $('.cd-cart-container'),
   cartPrice = i.data("price"),
   cartBody = cartWrapper.find('.body'),
   cartList = cartBody.find('.cd-cart-items');
   productAdded = $('<li><span class="cd-qty">1x</span>Produto<div class="cd-price">'+cartPrice+'</div><a href="#" class="cd-item-remove cd-img-replace">Remove</a></li>');
   cartList.prepend(productAdded);
   console.log("Valor dentro da função: "+cartPrice);
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="add-to-cart" data-price="25.99">
    <em>Adicionar ao Carrinho</em>
    <svg x="0px" y="0px" width="32px" height="32px" viewBox="0 0 32 32">
        <path stroke-dasharray="19.79 19.79" stroke-dashoffset="19.79" fill="none" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="square" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M9,17l3.9,3.9c0.1,0.1,0.2,0.1,0.3,0L23,11"/>
    </svg>
</button>
```

Comment: Cara, tu é foda. obrigado, me ajudou demais.

Comment: @ThomasFranklin De nada broder! Precisando tamos aí. Abs!